# Filter ObservableList dynamically by property value

Tags: java, javafx, dynamic, properties, observable

I am writing a Log Reader application using JavaFX and I want to implement search-based filtering, based on the selected property.
[Application screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3YEm.png)
The values in the Combobox represents names of fields of objects, which populate the table. Now, I want to display only the rows (objects) whose property contains typed text.

My objects that populate the table look like this:

```
public class LogEvent {

private final SimpleStringProperty timestamp = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private final SimpleStringProperty level = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private final SimpleStringProperty emitter = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private final SimpleStringProperty message = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private final SimpleStringProperty thread = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private final SimpleStringProperty mdc = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private final SimpleStringProperty stackTrace = new SimpleStringProperty("");

public LogEvent(String timestamp, String level, String emitter, String message, String thread, String mdc, String stackTrace) {
    this.timestamp.set(timestamp);
    this.level.set(level);
    this.emitter.set(emitter);
    this.message.set(message);
    this.stackTrace.set(stackTrace);
    this.thread.set(thread);
    this.mdc.set(mdc);
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp.get();
}

public String getLevel() {
    return level.get();
}

public String getEmitter() {
    return emitter.get();
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message.get();
}

public String getStackTrace() {
    return stackTrace.get();
}

public String getThread() {
    return thread.get();
}

public String getMdc() {
    return mdc.get();
}
```

}

Now, to filter the events I am trying to do something along the lines:

```
private void filterEvents(String text) {
    String property = filterCombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toLowerCase();
    if (!property.isEmpty() && text != null) {
        FilteredList<LogEvent> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(events);
        filteredList.setPredicate(event -> event.getProperty(property).contains(text));
        tableView.setItems(filteredList);
        tableView.refresh();
    }
}
```

Of course there is no such method. I know I could use reflections, or write some switch, but that doesn't seem like a good idea. Is there some cleaner way to achieve this? For example something similar to how I'm creating table columns dynamically, using PropertyValueFactory:

```
for (String keyword : keywords) {
        TableColumn<LogEvent, String> column = new TableColumn<>(keyword);
        column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(keyword.toLowerCase()));
        tableView.getColumns().add(column);
    }
```

Each row is color-coded by it's level severity.

```
tableView.setRowFactory(tableView -> new TableRow<>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(LogEvent item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null) {
                        switch (item.getLevel()) {
                            case LogLevel.ERROR:
                                setStyle("-fx-background-color: indianred;");
                                break;
                            case LogLevel.INFO:
                                setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornflowerblue;");
                                break;
                            case LogLevel.WARN:
                                setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");
                                break;
                            case LogLevel.DEBUG:
                                setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightblue;");
                                break;
                            case LogLevel.TRACE:
                                setStyle("-fx-background-color: ivory");
                                break;
                            case LogLevel.FATAL:
                                setStyle("-fx-background-color: firebrick");
                                break;
                            default:
                                setStyle("-fx-backgound-color: white;");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    );
```

Comment: `PropertyValueFactory` ***does*** use reflection. Of course it's possible to create a similar class...

Comment: I saw, but I was wondering if there is any other way.

Comment: whatever you do, if table.refresh seems to be the answer, something is wrong with your setup - anyway, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `tableView.refresh()` is there because I have a rowFactory, that defines a color for each row based on level severity and if the table is not refreshed, the empty rows will remain colored. Updated question with the code.

Comment: repeating: there is something wrong with your setup/context .. no way to dig into without a [mcve] ..

Comment: I've found where the problem was. In my implementation of TableRowFactory, only not null rows are updated, so if there are fewer items in the filtered list, leftover cells are left colored as they were.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have a few options, but here is one using Reflection. You did say that you were aware you could do so, but I'm not sure there's a way around it.

Full disclosure: I am not a Java expert by any means so this is likely not the best approach. It does work, however.

---

First, we need to update the `LogEvent` class to include a couple of helper methods:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LogEvent {

    private final SimpleStringProperty timestamp = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty level = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty emitter = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty message = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty thread = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public LogEvent(String timestamp, String level, String emitter, String message, String thread) {
        this.timestamp.set(timestamp);
        this.level.set(level);
        this.emitter.set(emitter);
        this.message.set(message);
        this.thread.set(thread);

    }

    // Allows our filter functionality to retrieve a list of this object's Property objects
    public static List<String> getPropertiesList() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        // Let's loop through all our methods, looking for any that end in "Property"
        for (Method method : LogEvent.class.getMethods()) {
            String name = method.getName();

            // If it's a Property, return just the name of the property
            if (name.endsWith("Property")) {
                list.add(name.replace("Property", ""));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public Object getPropertyByName(String propertyName) throws Exception {
        Method method = this.getClass().getMethod(propertyName + "Property", (Class[]) null);
        return method.invoke(this);
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty timestampProperty() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp.set(timestamp);
    }

    public String getLevel() {
        return level.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty levelProperty() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(String level) {
        this.level.set(level);
    }

    public String getEmitter() {
        return emitter.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty emitterProperty() {
        return emitter;
    }

    public void setEmitter(String emitter) {
        this.emitter.set(emitter);
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty messageProperty() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message.set(message);
    }

    public String getThread() {
        return thread.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty threadProperty() {
        return thread;
    }

    public void setThread(String thread) {
        this.thread.set(thread);
    }
}
```

---

Now a simple program to demonstrate (comments in code):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FilteredTableViewSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // First, let's create some sample LogEvent data
        ObservableList<LogEvent> events = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        events.add(new LogEvent("4:02 pm", "Warning", "Emitter #1", "You're gonna need a bigger boat!", "Thread-03"));
        events.add(new LogEvent("3:34 am", "Info", "Emitter #1", "Who you gonna call?", "Thread-05"));
        events.add(new LogEvent("4:02", "Warning", "Emitter #1", "Be excellent to each other!", "Thread-JFX"));
        events.add(new LogEvent("4:02", "Warning", "Emitter #1", "What we have here is a failure to communicate.", "Thread-JFX"));

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Add our ComboBox and filter TextField
        HBox filterPane = new HBox(5);
        filterPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        ComboBox<String> cboProperty = new ComboBox<>();
        cboProperty.setPromptText("Filter By...");
        cboProperty.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(LogEvent.getPropertiesList()));

        TextField txtFilter = new TextField();
        HBox.setHgrow(txtFilter, Priority.ALWAYS);
        filterPane.getChildren().addAll(cboProperty, txtFilter);

        // Just a standard TableView
        TableView<LogEvent> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<LogEvent, String> colTimestamp = new TableColumn<>("Timestamp");
        TableColumn<LogEvent, String> colLevel = new TableColumn<>("Level");
        TableColumn<LogEvent, String> colEmitter = new TableColumn<>("Emitter");
        TableColumn<LogEvent, String> colMessage = new TableColumn<>("Message");
        TableColumn<LogEvent, String> colThread = new TableColumn<>("Thread");
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(colTimestamp, colLevel, colEmitter, colMessage, colThread);

        // Setup our CellValueFactories
        colTimestamp.setCellValueFactory(tv -> tv.getValue().timestampProperty());
        colLevel.setCellValueFactory(tv -> tv.getValue().levelProperty());
        colEmitter.setCellValueFactory(tv -> tv.getValue().emitterProperty());
        colMessage.setCellValueFactory(tv -> tv.getValue().messageProperty());
        colThread.setCellValueFactory(tv -> tv.getValue().threadProperty());

        FilteredList<LogEvent> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(events);
        tableView.setItems(filteredList);

        // Finally, we create our filter functionality
        txtFilter.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            final String searchString = newValue.toUpperCase();
            filteredList.setPredicate(logEvent -> {

                // If the search field is empty or no Filtered By value is selected, show all LogEvents
                if (searchString.isEmpty() || cboProperty.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null) {
                    return true;
                }

                // Now we just add our checks for each possible search field
                String filterBy = cboProperty.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

                // We retrieve the text for the property we're looking for
                String targetString = "";
                try {
                    targetString = ((StringProperty) logEvent.getPropertyByName(filterBy)).getValue();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Now, return true if there's a match
                return targetString.toUpperCase().contains(searchString.toUpperCase());

            });

        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(filterPane, tableView);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(600);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

> **The Result:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: was about to edit just for being able to retract my downvote - when I realized again what's wrong <g> there is no need to reset the items after filtering - just configure the table with the filteredList right from the start and then update its predicate